# Using element's attribute value as a selector in CSS

Tags: css, svg, css-selectors, attributes

I've been trying to create an interactive SVG where changing certain custom attributes changes the SVG but I ran into a bit of a trouble - I want to switch between different air vent system modes by passing the name of the mode as an attribute and I couldn't find an easy way to hide or show different icons for those modes.

---

Basically the question is - is there any way to use the value of an element's attribute as a selector without knowing what the value is beforehand?

---

Consider this CSS code:

```
#root[Mode="some_mode"] [id=attr(Mode)] {
    /* .. style .. */
}
```

And this SVG code:

```
<g id="root" Mode="some_mode">
    <g id="mode1" />
    <g id="mode2" />
    <!-- and so on -->
</g>
```

This seems like the most obvious and logical way to do this but it doesn't work, so I resorted to a hacky way of doing this:

```
#root[Mode="standby"] #standby { visibility: visible; }
#root[Mode="comfort"] #comfort { visibility: visible; }
#root[Mode="economy"] #economy { visibility: visible; }
/* and so on for every mode that I have */
```

I know that this can be done using JS but the trick is that this SVG has to be JS-less (it's for a SCADA system that uses SVGs for custom graphics).

Thanks in advance for helping!

Comment: can you share the real SVG with all its content? probably there is another easier way to deal with this instead of selectors

Comment: yeah, sure, hope PasteBin is fine: [Mode.SVG](https://pastebin.com/pbUSC6Lg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since CSS is declarative I think the correct (albeit verbose) approach really is:

```
[Mode="standby"] #standby,
[Mode="comfort"] #comfort,
[Mode="economy"] #economy {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: well, sadly, is seems like it really is; accepting your answer as solution

Comment: Notwithstanding, your CSS syntax suggestion of `[id=attr(Mode)]` (and variations (such as `[id$=attr(Mode)]`) is a very smart one. The CSS `attr()` function will be much more useful when it (eventually) evolves. The latest info I can find on it is here: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-4/#attr-notation